# Simulating pop ups in windows javascript app

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

I'm porting my webpage chat to windows 8 javascript app. I need to simulate pop-ups like alert, prompt, confirm,... Creating the box isn't problem, but the main part is that I need to pause script execution somehow until user clicks the button.

Is there any way to do it (I know that in pure javascript, it is hard, but I think that there may be some kind of windows native function to pause execution (or there may be some way to implement alert,... directly))?

Comment: You can't pause execution...there is no way to make it work like a real alert/confirm/prompt.

Comment: OK then, I want the prompt to ask user to enter his username. What would be best alternative to do that? This is my current code: while (str_nickname === null || str_nickname.length == 0) {
  str_nickname = prompt('Choose your nickname');
 }

Comment: Isn't that if you need to execute a loop and it requires certain parameter to be entered by the user(like if else loop) so until the user enters the required condition the loop will not execute

Comment: You would have to use a callback like any asynchronous method needs. Think xmlhttprequest.

Comment: ever heard of showModalDialog

Answer (score 0):

epascarello-- why do you say that its not makeable, if you dont know it.

use Method showModalDialog , search for it,